# How to stop a java scanner without ending a loop

Tags: java, loops, infinite

This may be a strange question but is there way to stop a scanner in an infinite loop if an if statement comes out as true or false?

For example if you have:

```
  for (;;) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int a = in.nextInt();
  if (a <= 0) {
  // is there something I could put in here to end the loop?
  } 
  else { System.out.println("Continue"); }
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `break;` the loop if the condition in `if` is `true` and the control goes in

```
for (;;) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int a = in.nextInt();
  if (a <= 0) {
  break;
  } 
  else { System.out.println("Continue"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `break;` you could also use a while loop and test at each iteration the value inputted by the user :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int a;
while((a = in.nextInt()) > 0){
    System.out.println("Continue");
}
System.out.println("finish");
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution.It's a "cleaner" step compared to using a `break`

Answer (score 0):

Use `break;`, but you shouldn´t abuse it, it would be better to set the for condition properly

Answer (score 0):

Using a `break;` solves your problem.Like this

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
public static void main (String[]args) { 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
// Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0; i< 3;i++) {
System.out.println("Enter a number");
int a = in.nextInt();
if (a <= 0) {
break;// is there something I could put in here to end the loop?
} 
 else { System.out.println("Continue"); }
}
}}
```